# Why won't OpenERP7/Odoo restore a database when running via Docker behind an NGINX reverse proxy?

Tags: odoo

Setup:

1.[OpenERP/Odoo](https://hub.docker.com/r/tinyerp/ubuntu-openerp/) installed in a Docker environment as a single file. In other words, OpenERP/Odoo and a PostgreSQL database are installed by running a single "run" command.

2. [NGINX](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) used as a reverse proxy
3. Restore database over 1Mb in size.

Reference:
[Error message in restoring database via both zip file and dump file for Odoo 8](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/error-message-in-restoring-database-via-both-zip-file-and-dump-file-for-odoo-8-91430)

Symptoms:

1. OpenERP/Odoo starts to upload database but then states that database cannot be restored while at the same time advising that the database has been restored.
2. Database is not available at the central OpenERP/Odoo log-in screen.

Answer (score 0):

For newbies like myself the experience of this problem was particularly frustrating. The problem stems from a default setting within NGINX that limits NGINX interaction with a client (the computer used to restore the database to OpenERP/Odoo) to a 1Mb upload. As a result, the database restoration feature of OpenERP/Odoo appears broken. Thankfully, the reference in the question above hinted at the problem and the solution. Included below is a more richly documented instruction set on correcting the NGINX configuration that prevents Openerp/Odoo database restoration.

1. [Attach to Docker container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505506/how-to-get-bash-or-ssh-into-a-running-container-in-background-mode)

   $ docker exec -it [containerIdOrName] bash
2. If this is the first time trying to modify NGINX install VI

   $ apt-get update

   $ apt-get install vim
3. [Set client_max_body_size to 0 to disable body size checking](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-nginx-configuration)

   See [Module ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) for more information on settings

   $ vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

   ```
   http{ ...

       client_max_body_size 0;

   }
   ```
4. Exit out of NGINX container

   $ exit
5. Restart NGINX container

   $ docker restart [containerIdOrName]
6. Give database restoration a try.

Please post corrections or additions to this method to sweeten the process up for others that are struggling bushwhacking their way through virtualization.